# xampp with a specified port number not working with virtualhost

Tags: apache, dns, xampp, virtualhost

I am trying to create a local domain name for my xampp project

But the dns is not resolving it is not redirecting correctly.

/hosts/etc

```
127.0.0.1:8081      mydomainname.test
```

virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sam"
    ServerName mydomainname.test
    ServerAlias mydomainname.test
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/sam">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    Options All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the file a little

```
Listen 8081

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sam"
    ServerName mydomainname.test
    ServerAlias mydomainname.test
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/sam">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    Options All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Read more here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html#port

Comment: @etranz Did you restart apache after changing the virtualhosts?

Comment: yes I restarted xampp

Comment: @etranz Then you have to debug it more. I can not help anymore here. Fixing the virtualhost file was the first step. But the rest needs way more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's `/etc/hosts`. And it does not accept ports and should look like:
`mydomainname.test 127.0.0.1`